# How to increase the total number of iterations it takes to converge a MDP?

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, policy-iteration

I was reading about [Policy Iteration](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/first/ebook/node43.html). What are the factors that influence the total number of iterations the algorithm takes to converge?

For a given MDP which converges in 3 iterations, what setting needs to be influenced for the MDP so that the total number of iterations increase?

I am experimenting with my simple MDP and trying to understand the conditions, under which a normal MDP might take a lot many iterations before it converges. I have assumed a constant discount factor of 0.75